# jQuery (billy.carousel) - Carousel going nuts sometimes

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

thanks in advance if you're willing to beam me up with a solution. I'm working on a site http://tecnointelcom.com/new/ -- and there is a carousel in the homepage. I'm using a jQuery Plugin "Billy the Carousel", from time to time it gets nuts and jumps from slide to another in less than 1 second (periodically, so about 5 slides in 3 seconds), but the indicator is still in the anchor of the a slide (it does not go nuts like the slider).

the jquery plugin is in (same route as prev link)/js/billy.carousel.jquery.js

the init file is in (same route as prev link)/js/init.js

Pls... could anyone see this and reply with something I must be missing in the code?

Thx, Alex

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the plugin is queuing functions that contain animations with [setInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/window.setInterval). The latest modern browsers have begun to implement feature called [requestAnimationFrame()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.mozRequestAnimationFrame) to save resources. Essentially, your animation calls are being stacked up while your tab with the carousel in it is out of focus or hidden. When the tab regains focus, [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) executes them all at the same time. jQuery advises you not to do this. From their [.animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) documentation:

> Because of the nature of requestAnimationFrame(), you should never queue animations using a setInterval or setTimeout loop. In order to preserve CPU resources, browsers that support requestAnimationFrame will not update animations when the window/tab is not displayed. If you continue to queue animations via setInterval or setTimeout while animation is paused, all of the queued animations will begin playing when the window/tab regains focus. To avoid this potential problem, use the callback of your last animation in the loop, or append a function to the elements .queue() to set the timeout to start the next animation.

You could also clear the object's fx queue with [.clearQueue()](http://api.jquery.com/clearQueue/) right before the animation starts. At line 160 of billy.carousel.jquery.js:

```
object.clearQueue().animate({'marginLeft': "0"}, option.scrollSpeed);
```